# Setting up seperate audio and video files using ffmpeg while straming rtsp to wowza

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming, wowza

I use the following command to stream to wowza server over rtsp;

> ffmpeg -re -i 1464197749623.mkv -c:v copy -c:a copy -strict
>   experimental -f rtsp rtsp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/myStream

It works fine.

However, I have a situation where I only get the **video** from mkv file but not **audio**. I get separate audio file in mkv format.
How can I specify audio and video source separately in above ffmpeg command so it can stream combiningly to wowza ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> How can I specify audio and video source separately in above ffmpeg command so it can stream combiningly to wowza ?

Add another input and explicitly map each stream:

```
ffmpeg -re -i video.mkv -re -i audio.mka -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -c copy rtsp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/myStream
```

- See [`-map` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options).
- You can use `-c copy` instead of `-c:v copy -c:a copy`.
- I saw no need for the `-strict experimental` option so I removed it.
- The `-f rtsp` option is likely superfluous so I removed it.

Comment: It only picks up the first source and ignores the second. But I want to merge those 2 sources and stream to wowza

Comment: RESOLVED :)
@LordNeckbeard - I followed the instructions on manual and adjusted the command to get video (-map 0:0 ) of first file  and audio (-map 1:1) of second file overall command being:

ffmpeg -re -i video.mkv -re -i audio.mkv -c copy -map 0:0 -map 1:1 -f rtsp rtsp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/myStream